# Ignore UserName property with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

My app uses ASP.NET identity but makes no use of the `UserName` property as users log in using `Email` instead.  So I'd like to remove it from the database table to keep things tidy, which I've done with the following code:

```
public class UserEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserEntityConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("User");

        Property(u => u.Id).HasColumnOrder(0);
        Property(u => u.Title).HasMaxLength(50).HasColumnOrder(1);
        Property(u => u.FullName).HasMaxLength(256).IsRequired().HasColumnOrder(2);
        Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(512).IsRequired().HasColumnOrder(3);
        Property(u => u.EmailConfirmed).HasColumnOrder(4);
        Property(u => u.PasswordHash).HasColumnOrder(5);
        Property(u => u.SecurityStamp).HasMaxLength(256).HasColumnOrder(6);
        Ignore(u => u.UserName);  // not used
        Ignore(u => u.PhoneNumber);  // not used
        Ignore(u => u.PhoneNumberConfirmed);  // not used

    }
}
```

If I leave the `UserName` property unset, I get the run-time error

> Name cannot be null or empty.

If I then try to set the property, I get this error instead:

> The specified type member 'UserName' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

because there isn't a database column to map the property to.

Is it possible to use ASP.NET Identity without having a UserName column in the User table (that in my case would not be used)?

Comment: You can do it, but it'll involve a significant rewrite of a lot of tested code. I say it is a waste of time for no good reason. Just let it be there, it does not eat much space.

Comment: Thanks @trailmax - how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible with the default `IdentityUser`. The UserName Property is also used for authentification.

You maybe have to write your own identity or just 'ignore' it (let it be).